# How do you build complex queries with MongoDB and the C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have developed a simple API which allows you to build up an array of search criteria within a MongoDB Collection. I now need to be able to convert this array into an actual Mongo Query, and this part is where I am having extreme difficulty.

Ideally I am after some syntax that will allow me to do the following pseudo code:

```
var query = new QueryBuilder();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    switch (group.Condition)
    {
        case GroupCondition.Or:
            query.Or(group.Queries);
        break;
        case GroupCondition.And:
            query.And(group.Queries);
        break;
    }
}
return myCollection.FindAs(type, query);
```

I actually want to build up slightly more complex queries, but ultimately I am after the functionality to dynamically build up my queries with objects as seen in my pseudo code above.

Feel free to ask me for additional details if I have not made myself clear enough about what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So before you get too far, you should look into using Linq.

Comment: Same here. I see a few people use examples of Query with multiple query expressions chained together however, when I do this like Query.EQ().GT(); it doesn't work as EQ/GT don't return a query object. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have the right idea...  There is a class called Query that is essentially a query builder without the instantiation.

using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;

Query.And, Query.Or, etc... are all there.  It is the same thing that is used underneath the linq provider to build up complex queries.

Comment: Can somebody actually point at an example that shows multiple query selectors strung together? Looks like Query is not chainable.

Comment: @RickStrahl build it up like an AST.  
Query.And(
  Query.OR(
    Query.EQ("x", 1),
    Query.EQ("y", 2)),
  Query.GT("z", 3));

Comment: @RickStrahl I ended up making a bespoke Query Language which breaks down, and then compiles into Mongo Queries (hence asking this question). The Query Language got scrapped in the end, but it did work (with a number of tests!). Do you still need help? I've been tempted to re-create it and public as OSS - maybe even publish a NuGet package for some of the helpers.